# Mockito verify that method is called with correct argument using regex

Tags: java, regex, tdd, mockito, bdd

## Description

I am trying to test the following class:

```
Class UserSynchronizer(){
   private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = ... ;

   public Sync(candidate) { 
     ...
     if (candidate.inValidForSync()) {
       log.debug("Candidate #" + candidate.getId() + ": Not syncing");
     }
     else {
       log.debug("Syncing");
     }
   }

 }
```

I want to see if mockito can detect what arguments `log.debug` was called with and then I want to see if I can do some kind of regex check on it. In other words, I want to:

- capture the arguments provided to the log object (which I am mocking in my test atm)
- check (using regex) if it matches a pattern like "Candidate #\d+: Not syncing" for the cases where my mock candidate object is returning false

## Test code

The code below is what I have as a starting point:

```
public void verifySyncDoesntSyncWhenInvalid(){
  //Setup candidate mock
  Candidate invalidSyncCandidateMock = mock(Candidate.class);
  when(invalidSyncCandidateMock.inValidForSync()).thenReturn(true);

  //Setup log mock
  UserSynchronizer userSynchronizer = ...;
  Field logField = userSynchronizer.getClass().getDeclaredField("log");
  logField.setAccessible(true);
  logField.set(userSynchronizer, logMock);

  //Call sync
  userSynchronizer.sync(invalidSyncCandidateMock);

  //Verify that debug was called with ("Candidate #\d+: Not syncing")
  ???
}
```

## Problem

The problem is that `log.debug` is called multiple times. I want to capture the arguments that are provided to `log.debug` and ensure that when it is called with the candidate that is invalid for sync, then the logger object correctly logs that the candidate was not synced.

Edit: If this has been asked before, I apologize. I kindly ask that you post a link to the related question :)

Comment: Now, that is an original way to replace a field for testing :p

Comment: @fge  I'm using reflection to replace the field, but if there is a better way, feel free to let me know :)

Comment: Well, maybe use a dedicated `LoggerFactory` which gives mock loggers? You seem to be using log4j so I can't help there (I use slf4j + logback myself)

Comment: @ArnabDatta since you accepted an answer that explains how to capture the arguments of multiple calls, please change the title of the question. The accepted answer says nothing about the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
final List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();

final Answer<Void> catchMeAll = new Answer<Void>()
{
    @Override
    public Void answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation)
    {
        messages.add((String) invocation.getArguments()[0]);
    }
}

doAnswer(catchMeAll).when(logMock).debug(anyString());
```

(note: this code assumes that the `Logger`'s `.debug()` method returns `void`; I don't know of any `Logger` which does not, but who knows)

Comment: The problem is that log.debug is called multiple times as I stated in the question. How would I capture them all? :o

Comment: You mean, in that `candidate()` function?

Comment: No, elsewhere in the `sync` function. Note the use of `...`at the start of the function :)

Comment: Well, that didn't tell me whether other messages were logged at all :p See edited answer

Comment: I mentioned it explicitly in the problem description :)

Comment: I would add that your original answer using ArgumentCaptor wasn't wrong either. I used `ArgumentCaptor.getAllValues()" to extract all log messages :)

Answer (score 16):

Mockito provides regex matcher in standard [org.mockito.Matchers](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.8.0-rc2/org/mockito/Matchers.java?av=f) class. Here is an example how this function can be used to verify invocation with proper parameter value:

```
verify(restMock, times(1)).exchange(matches(".*text=welcome.*to.*blah"), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(ResponseEntity.class), eq(String.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to match this would be to use a regex-capable Hamcrest matcher:

```
verify(logMock).debug(argThat(matchesPattern("Candidate #\\d+: Not syncing")));
```

Note that you'd have to write your own, or use the not-yet-included [PatternMatcher](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/issues/detail?id=194#c1) or [`hamcrest-text-patterns`](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/issues/detail?id=2) as in [JavaHamcrest issue #2](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/issues/detail?id=2).